# PayPal IPN with credit card

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, credit-card

Now I have a PayPal "Buy Now" button on the site and everything works fine. By clicking on this button, the buyer enters his PayPal account and pays for the purchase, as a result, after an IPN check, he receives a letter with a link to download the file and a serial number for authorization of the program. But now I want to make sure that not only those who have a PayPal account can buy, but also those who do not have this account, i.e. credit card.
I know that for this you need to activate the corresponding option in your PayPal account, but I had this question: where will the letter with the link and serial number be sent? Now I do not know the email address.
How to make the buyer specify an email before payment, to which he will receive a letter with a link to the purchased file and the serial number and how to make this email added to the database after checking the IPN? Currently, this email address is taken from IPN data.

Comment: You can define any button to be accompanied by a text field with a prompt.

Comment: @EJP Thank you! But I want to clarify - ie, I can add in the form of the "_Buy now_" button one more field with the name `custom` and with the parameter `email`, to which the buyer can enter his email address (if he does not have a PayPal account) and this email will be sent together with the IPN and I can get it and add it to my database if the `payer_email` field is empty? Did I understand you correctly?